# Is it always recommended to backup and restore the SharePoint content Database?

Tags: sharepoint

Is it always recommended to backup and restore the SharePoint content Database?
We always face an Issue of system un-stability, workflow not working properly after content db restore. So, I wan't to know that is it OK to restore content DB or we only should use it as a backup plan for disaster situations?

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Yes" and you can use it for both situations.

Here are some more benefits that you get by backing up and restoring SharePoint content databases.

It will help to Protect your organization from data loss with truly comprehensive backup for your entire SharePoint environment, including all content, customizations, solutions, apps, Recycle Bins, features, and the VMs hosting your SharePoint servers.

Also , it minimizes business disruption caused by service interruptions or accidental deletions with efficient recovery of all SharePoint backup components, databases, indexes, and configurations.

You can track, manage, and report on all SharePoint backup and restore processes through a centralized management platform. Monitor and enforce compliance with SharePoint SLAs.